# csrf varification not working if script is in static folder

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-templates

javascript:

```
   $('.delete').click(function() {  
          if (confirm("Are you sure to delete?")) {      
          var csrf_token = $("#csrf_token").val();    
          $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
            data:{
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: ('{{csrf_token}}'),
                delete:true
            },
            type:'POST',
            url: '/feed_list/', 
            cache:false,
            success: function() { 
                window.location.href = window.location;
            }
        });
        return false;
      }
    });
```

This is my java script function to call a method in views.py which perform delete function.Delete function is working fine,my problem is now this javascript function is in my current html page.If i move this function to static folder-->scripts --> custom.js it throws 403 error page.`CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.` I am passing csrf token in form as well as in java script.I want to solve this.Need suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to work, since the django server doesn't render js files.
Here's how you can solve this:

Add jquery plugin:
http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

Use this in your js file to get csrf token:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken: $.cookie('csrftoken'),
```

Comment: But scripts in other pages worked if i move js to static folder,problem is with two pages.

Comment: @user2439275  presumably those other scripts didn't use template tags.

Comment: @DanielRoseman that means the answer is the perfect solution,other than this is no way...!

Comment: @user2439275 Did my solution helped?, if not, explain the error

Answer (score 0):

You've already defined `csrf_token` so you need to pass it in ajax request:

```
data:{
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf_token,
            delete:true
        }
```

But i don't know how your input looks like, i define token as

```
token = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()
```

and in base template pass `{% csrf_token %}` which html code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="your_token">
```